# VHDL - Object Class For Formal Parameter of function cant be a variable

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am trying to write some VHDL to make a sign magnitude addition (overload +) without using any + in the code. Using Quartus 2 13.0 Cyclonce IV E EP4ce115F29C7

When I try to compile my current project, I get the stack trace: [image]

which points me to this line:

```
variable sum:std_logic_vector(max downto 0);
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong, I have looked for material on this but couldn't really find anything.

Here is my code:

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

package SIGN_MAGNITUDE_ARITH is 
    constant word_size: positive := 32;
    type SIGN_MAG is array(natural range <>) of std_logic;
    function "+"(L:SIGN_MAG; R:SIGN_MAG;) return SIGN_MAG;
    --function "-"(L: SIGN_MAG; R: SIGN_MAG;) return SIGN_MAG;
    --function "*"(L: SIGN_MAG; R: SIGN_MAG;) return SIGN_MAG;
    --procedure "/"(signal Z, D: in SIGN_MAG; signal Q,R: out SIGN_MAG);
end;

package body SIGN_MAGNITUDE_ARITH is
    -- Sign Magnitude addition (overload "+")
    function "+"(L: SIGN_MAG; R: SIGN_MAG;) return SIGN_MAG is
        constant max = (MAX(R'length, L'length));
        variable carry:std_logic:='0';
        variable sum:std_logic_vector(max downto 0);
    begin
        if(L(L'length-1)='0') and (R(R'length-1)='0') then
            for i in 0 to max - 2 loop
                sum(i):= L(i) xor R(i) xor carry;
                carry:=( L(i) and R(i) ) or ( L(i) and carry ) or ( R(i) and carry );
            end loop;
            sum(max-1):=carry;
            sum(max):='0';
        end if;
        return sum;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You have an extra ; after the R paramter. But why are you trying to redefine something that has existed for over 25 years?

Comment: Besides the extra semicolon at the end of parameter lists (where semicolons are separators not delimiters), MAX is a local function to the package body in numeric_std (see IEEE Std 1076.3-1997). The constant max declaration is missing a semicolon, a type_mark and a ":=". There's a function MAXIMUM implicitly declared immediately following scalar type declarations in -2008 and for type INTEGER it's used in the numeric_std package body. `return sum';` should be `return SIGN_MAG(sum);` They are closely related types but don't share a base type.

Comment: In general VHDL analyzers (compilers) for simulators have better error messages than synthesis tools.

Comment: @Tricky I am working on a school assignment for digital design to make a sign overloaded add without using the addition. Prof hates us.

Comment: @user1155120 thanks for catching that :=, would it impact if I changed sum to sum:SIGN_MAG(max downto 0); ?

Comment: @Travis   Do change the type of sum to SIGN_MAG.

Comment: Changing the type of sum to SIGN_MAG would also work. The element type of SUM_REG is std_logic, where the operator overload functions "xor" , "and" and "or" are declared in package std_logic_1164.